# Non-breaking space("&#xA0;") is not transformed correctly in IE9 and IE11 while doing XSLT transformation

Tags: xslt, browser, cross-browser

We are doing client-side `XSL transformation` over documents with `ISO-8859-1` encoding.  Works fine in `IE7` and `IE8`.  However, when we run in `IE9`,`IE11` the actual transformation works perfectly, but the non-breaking spaces ("`&#xA0;`") are no longer maintained in the transformation.

Instead of the non-breaking space, it puts in the "`replacement character`" (renders as a `question mark inside a dark diamond`).

If we flip to `Compatibility Mode`, the non-breaking space is properly rendered as part of the transformation.
This seems to be a bug in the XSL processor that is in IE9 -- the non-breaking spaces should be transformed correctly.

If there some way around this issue ?

image shown below is the image of replacement character by `IE9` and `IE11`.

[image: image displayed instead of space]

> Warning/error messages from IE11 console -

```
    HTML1300: Navigation occurred.
    File: Test
    XML5001: Applying Integrated XSLT Handling.
    HTML1524: Invalid HTML5 DOCTYPE. Consider using the interoperable form "<!DOCTYPE html>".
    File: Test, Line: 3, Column: 1
    HTML1114: Codepage utf-8 from (10) overrides conflicting codepage iso-8859-1 from (META tag)
    File: Test
    HTML1504: Unexpected end tag.
    File: Test, Line: 380, Column: 1
    HTML1504: Unexpected end tag.
    File: Test, Line: 381, Column: 1
    HTML1504: Unexpected end tag.
    File: Test, Line: 476, Column: 1
    SEC7115: :visited and :link styles can only differ by color. Some styles were not applied to :visited.
    File: Test
```

> HTML1114: Codepage utf-8 from (10) overrides conflicting codepage iso-8859-1 from (META tag)

Not sure why IE11 is overriding the encoding given by server.

Comment: Please provide details of how you run the transformation, do you simply load an XML document with an `<?xml-stylesheet?>` processing instruction in a browser window? Or do you use Javascript to run the transformation? How does your code look like?

Comment: I am simply loading XML document with <?xml-stylesheet?> processing instruction not using java script

Comment: I have written a small test case http://home.arcor.de/martin.honnen/xslt/test2015112001.xml to try to reproduce the problem, it renders fine for me with IE 11 on Windows 10. Do you have a URL we can visit to see the problem? Does the XML declare the ISO-8859-1 encoding properly? How does the `xsl:output` directive in your XSLT look?

Comment: @MartinHonnen thanks for your help. even I have created a sample test case and I am not able to reproduce this issue. but in my application when xsl and xml are sent to browser by server we are facing this issue when browser does the transformation. I cant share actual xsl and xml file due to project restrictions.

Comment: Then you need to debug it yourself,  you say "sent to browser by server", I would check whether the HTTP response headers sent by the server perhaps override the XML declaration, e.g. the XML declares `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>` but the server sends `Content-Type: application/xml; charset=UTF-8` or at least a different encoding from the one used for the XML. That's something I would check with IE's developer tools (F12).

Comment: Below is the response header sent by server                                     `Key Value
Response HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date Fri, 20 Nov 2015 12:49:06 GMT
Server Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS) OpenSSL/1.0.1e-fips mod_jk/1.2.40
X-Powered-By Servlet/3.0; JBossAS-6
Access-Control-Allow-Origin *
Keep-Alive timeout=5, max=100
Connection Keep-Alive
Transfer-Encoding chunked
Content-Type text/xml`

Comment: @MartinHonnen This definitely seems be encoding issue, somehow IE11 is using **UTF-8** encoding because of which it is showing different character in case of non-breaking space, but I am not able to understand why IE11 is using **UTF-8** encoding when meta tag clearly says its **ISO-8859-1**

Comment: I am able to reproduce this with sample xsl and xml file for which I need to select encoding explicitly as **UTF-8** in IE11.

Comment: The messages suggest that you have two settings in the same document, do understand that with XSLT and output method `html` you should neither include a `DOCTYPE` nor a `meta` literally, instead, use the `xsl:output` directive and the XSLT processor will take care of outputting a `DOCTYPE` and `meta` as needed and as appropriate.

Comment: I don't have meta tag in my xsl I am using `xsl:output` directive only like below `<xsl:output method="html" doctype-public="-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" doctype-system="http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd"  encoding="ISO-8859-1" />` meta tag is generated by browser itself.

Comment: The line `HTML1502: Unexpected DOCTYPE. Only one DOCTYPE is allowed and it must occur before any elements.` suggests that your code contains a literal `DOCTYPE`.

Comment: `<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">` this is the doctype in my html page. error mentioned by you I was getting earlier when I had written doctype in CDATA inside xsl now I am using `xsl:output` tag so not getting that error. will update the error message.

Answer (score 2):

It's an encoding issue.  Seems likely to me that IE10/11 is trying to rencode this in UTF16 after it's already been encoded in ISO-8859-1.

I think your most likely fix for this would be to include a `<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">` in your `<head>` tag in the HTML.  I believe all versions of MSIE will respect this (or at least default to it if they ignore it).  I've had similar issues before in a different browser related context and that resolved it.

Comment: my html page is already having <meta charset="ISO-8859-1"> tag.

Comment: Hm.  What if you change it to UTF-8?  Or if you use the HTML 4 version of `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">`?  Could be that it's refusing to render `application/xml` in the ISO-8859-1?

Comment: I had tried changing it to UTF-8 but it didn't help.

Comment: my code is legacy code so it is using HTML 4 version of <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">. its not giving any kind of error while rendering.

Comment: Don't put that `meta` element in there, please use the `xsl:output` element to indicate the output encoding you want, the document type you want, the HTML version, and then the XSLT processor will add the `meta` as needed.